# PowerQuery transforming date from different region

Tags: string, date, parsing, powerquery

I'm trying to parse a date from a column in a dataset. The dates are strings written in the following format mm/dd/yyyy:

| Release_date.1 | Requirement_date.1 |
| --- | --- |
| 4/17/2025 | 12/17/2025 |
| 12/14/2023 | 5/21/2024 |
| 05/02/2023 | 8/21/2023 |
| 05/08/2023 | 8/28/2023 |
| 05/08/2023 | 09/04/2023 |
| 5/22/2023 | 09/11/2023 |
| 05/12/2023 | 09/04/2023 |
| 5/30/2023 | 9/18/2023 |
| 5/30/2023 | 9/25/2023 |

Using the default Parse function mixes up month and day and gives errors.

I tried googling and parse function, I've tried to modify the code, but just can't figure it out.

Comment: Did this answer work for you

Answer (score 0):

To make 12/31/2022 into 31/12/2022 use

=  Date.From([DateColumnName], "en-US")

To make 31/12/2022 into 12/31/2022 use

=  Date.From([DateColumnName], "en-GB")